# Add WHERE clause to single column

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, where-clause

I have a query which I am working on, basically I have 3 columns:

```
Code: The users Code
Orders Taken: The orders which have been taken
Orders Taken From an External Call
```

[image: http://gyazo.com/b412a5bb2980feb3220355fa4a8caf5a]

Basically I just need a way to only allow Orders From External Calls to have a where clauses, when I add in my WHERE clause, it does it for both tables.

My query so far:

```
SELECT T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode, 
    Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) AS [Orders Taken],
    Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) AS [Orders From External Calls]

    FROM T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls 
        INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory 
            ON (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CustomerCode = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) 
            AND (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CallDate = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.EntryDate)

    GROUP BY T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[Orders Taken]`? Is the MySQL tag correct?

Comment: That's just the name of the column

Comment: Where's the where clause?

Comment: To me don't have logical do what you said. If the both columns is the same, what's the logical to do where just on one? Or what's the difference?

Comment: It might be SQL and not MySQL then, also because I want two different columns to be displayed, I want one to show all the orders and one to only show certain orders, when I add in my WHERE clause it does the where for both of them

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right you should use CASE statement in the `[Orders From External Calls]` definition:

```
SELECT T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode, 
    Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) AS [Orders Taken],
    sum( CASE WHEN <Your condition here>  
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0
          END) AS [Orders From External Calls]

    FROM T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls 
        INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory 
            ON (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CustomerCode = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) 
            AND (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CallDate = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.EntryDate)

    GROUP BY T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want both of those `Orders` columns to count data from the same table, but with different restrictions on which records from the table are counted and which are not. So do something like:

```
SELECT T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode, 
    Count(SalesHistoryForAllOrders.CustomerCode) AS [Orders Taken],
    Count(SalesHistoryForExternalOrders.CustomerCode) AS [Orders From External Calls]

    FROM T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls 
        INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory SalesHistoryForAllOrders 
            ON (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CustomerCode = SalesHistoryForAllOrders.CustomerCode) 
            AND (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CallDate = SalesHistoryForAllOrders.EntryDate)
        INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory SalesHistoryForExternalOrders 
            ON (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CustomerCode = SalesHistoryForExternalOrders.CustomerCode) 
            AND (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CallDate = SalesHistoryForExternalOrders.EntryDate)

    GROUP BY T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode;
```

### Explanation:

By INNER JOINing the table two times and aliasing it each time, we now have two separate representations of the table to work with (called `SalesHistoryForAllOrders` and `SalesHistoryForExternalOrders`).

You are then free to place a WHERE clause that refers to either one of them separately, and it will ONLY affect that column, not the other one. So either do:

```
WHERE SalesHistoryForExternalOrders.IsAnExternalOrder > 0
```

or just add an additional AND to the second INNER JOIN:

```
AND SalesHistoryForExternalOrders.IsAnExternalOrder > 0
```

, the result is the same: that clause will only be applied the `External Calls` column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said on comments one column might have the count of all rows, and other column just show value on specify case.

So:

```
select table1.a,count(table1.b),
(select count(table2.c) from table2 where "where clause")
 from table1
```